# Checking an enum signature

Tags: typescript, enums

I am using an enum to keep translations for my code.

So for instance, I have in a file named "resources_eng" :

```
export enum ResourcesEnum {
    TXT_YES = "yes",
    TXT_NO = "no",
}
```

And in another file named "resources.spa":

```
export enum ResourcesEnum {
    TXT_YES = "si",
    TXT_NO = "no",
}
```

And finally I do in another file

```
import { ResourcesEnum as ResourcesEnumEng } from 'resources.eng';
import { ResourcesEnum as ResourcesEnumEsp } from 'resources.esp';

if (lang == "en") {
    this.enum = ResourcesEnumEng;
} else {
    this.enum = ResourcesEnumEsp;
}
```

But, I haven't been able to set "enum" to any type different to **any**, so I don't have any check.

I could have

```
export enum ResourcesEnum {
    TXT_YES = "si",
    TXT_NONONO = "no",
}
```

and I wouldn't get any error message.

Is there any way to give a type to my enums so that I can have an error at compile time ?

Comment: You could possibly write `enum: typeof ResourcesEnumEng | typeof ResourcesEnumEsp`, or `enum: Record<keyof ResourcesEnumEng, string>`, but I'm quite concerned about the intended use.  Usually people use enums where the *key* is for the developer, and the *value* is for the runtime.  Functions tend to accept enum *value*s.  But here it seems like you should probably be passing keys and not values, because the values are dependent on localization.  And therefore `enum` is a bad fit for this use case.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your comment !  But I am already using it, and beyond the lack of control, I have no problems. I am using litelement, and in my render functions I just use ${this.enum.TXT_YES}  without problems.  May be I don't understand your comment about being a bad fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the approach of using enums is the incorrect one here, you will never be able to get a merged type out of the two enums because they are different, since enums don't exist in javascript they get translated to objects, please read [enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

Your enum when transpiled will be:

```
const ResourcesEnum = {
    TXT_YES: "yes",
    TXT_NO: "no",
}
```

other approach used by apps like locize or phraseapp is something like this:

```js
interface translation {
  TXT_YES: string;
  TXT_NO: string;
}

const engTranslation: translation = {
  TXT_YES: 'yes',
  TXT_NO: 'no'
}
```

Which is in my opinion what you are really looking for, you should also take a look at the apps I mentioned and/or some other i18n library.

Comment: I agree, using an interface is the approach I was looking for. I was using i18n before, but I am now trying to solve it without libraries. I am using litelement and i18n doesn't seems the best option now. THANKS!